# How to use the values of pickerview with textview?

Tags: iphone

How to use the combine the data of picker view with Text view and use that both value in next view?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642400/how-to-combine-the-values-of-pickerview-with-textview

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use you picker's value and textView value in the next view. First variant - to make 2 properties in your next viewController and set them before pushing new viewController into stack. The second one - you can write your own initialization method, for example

> ```
> - (id) initWithTextViewValue:(NSString*)textViewValue{
>     if(self = [super init]){
>         textInCurrentController = textViewValue;
>     }
>     return self;
> }
> ```

And so on. Then you just can create your controller

> ```
> [[MyViewController alloc] initWithTextViewValue:textView.text];
> ```